# How to set transparency to single face of the custom geometry using Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've the custom geometry with sqaure-base and it looks like a cone. here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/suvKg/18/

I've obtained transparency to the whole object at here:

```
 var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.6, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
```

But I don't want transparency to be applied to base of the cone, but only side faces should have it. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial()` for your entire mesh. For example if your `geometry` have X faces and 2 differents materials :

```
var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.6, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } ),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 1, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } )
]; // the two materials 

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(yourGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)); //tell three.js that you will have several materials in your geometry
```

Then, you will need to determine `materialIndex` manualy in each of your faces based on the materials indexes

```
yourGeometry.faces[0].materialIndex = 0; 
yourGeometry.faces[1].materialIndex = 0;
yourGeometry.faces[2].materialIndex = 1; // <= the cone base 
...
yourGeometry.faces[lastFaceIndex].materialIndex = 0;
```

NB: default parameter for `materialIndex` is `0` so you will need to determine only one face to its material index in your case

Comment: note : i used faces[2] for your cone base but it's juste an example, you can adapt with your own geometry ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/suvKg/26/ this is my updated fiddle. I couldn't see my whole geometry after trying your approach. Could you please check with that?

Comment: the revision you used is the 50 so some little adaptations was needed to the mesh face material

Comment: plus you didn't initiate the face vertex uv

Comment: But now I'm looking to work in Three.js revision 54. Will this link work with revision 54?

Comment: 50: yourGeometry.materials = materials; var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(yourGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial()); 54: var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(yourGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));